# Storing count of records in SQL table

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

Lets say i have a table with posts, and each post has index of topic it belongs to. And i have a table with topics, with integer field, representing number of posts in this topic. When i create new post, i increase this value by 1, and then i delete post, i decrease value by 1.
I do it to not query database each time i need to count number of posts in certain topics.
But i heared that this approach may not be safe to use and actual number of posts in table may not match stored value.
Is there any ceratin info about how safe is it?

Comment: With triggers and transactions you can make this perfectly safe.

Comment: Queries to the database are executed one after the other. Since the increase or decrease of the count is a simple UPDATE query on a single table row, `UPDATE topic SET count = count + 1 WHERE id = 5`, this seems perfectly safe to me, even without triggers and transactions. What you should not do is first get the count from the database, change it in PHP, and then update the database with that new number. In that case you should definitely use transactions.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware if there is no trigger, then you have to manually update the counter every time you add or delete a post, which is not particularly safe. If you do not use transactions, then the insert or delete in the posts table may succeed, while the update to the counter fails, leaving again the counter out of sync.

Comment: @Shadow You're right, of course. The code might not be written correctly or the server could fail. In those cases triggers and transactions can save you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without transactions, the primary issue is timing.  Consider a delete and two users:

```
Time     User 1                    User 2
  1      count = count - 1
  2      update finishes           How many posts?
  3      delete post               Count returned
  4      delete finishes
```

Remember that actions such as updates and deletes take a finite amount of time -- even if they take effect all at once.  Because of this, User 2 will get the wrong number of posts.  This is a race condition; and it may or may not be an issue in your application.

Transactions fix this particular problem, by ensuring that resetting the count and deleting the post both take effect "at the same time".

A secondary issue is data quality.  Your data consistency checks are outside the database.  Someone can come directly into the database and say "Oh, these posts from user X should be removed".  That user might then delete those posts en masse -- but "forget" or not know to change the associated values.

This can be a big issue.  Triggers should solve this problem.